# jquery.form validate runs before jquery.ui datepicker completes field completion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, validation, datepicker

I have the following jquery validate attached to a form with two datepicker fields:

```
$("#submitform").validate(
        {
            debug: true,
            rules: {
                summary: {
                    validateWidthLimits: {max: 49, min: 5}
                },
                description: {
                    validateWidthLimits: {max: 49, min: 5}
                },
                start_date: { //HERE**
                    validateDate: {field: "#end_date", when: "before"}
                },
                end_date: { //HERE**                        
                    validateDate: {field: "#start_date", when: "after"}
                },
                geocomplete: {
                    validateWidthLimits: {max: 500, min: 5}
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(event, validator) {
                // submitForm();
                return false;
            },
            invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
                setFeedback2($("#mainfbf"), "All required fields must be filled out", true);
                return false;
            }
    });
```

When i choose a date using datepicker with for example start_date, I want start_date to check that it's before end_date, and vice versa for end_date.

The validation function is:

```
$.validator.addMethod("validateDate",   function(value, element, param) {
if (!value) {
    message = "*";
} else if (!value.match(/^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d\d$/)) {
    message = "Format dd/mm/yyyy";
}
//default to true
var fieldComparison = true;

//Validate against another date field (before:after)
if (param.field) {
    var compareTo = $(param.field).val();

    var compareToDate = Date.parse(compareTo,"dd/MM/yyyy");
    var valueDate = Date.parse(value, "dd/MM/yyyy");
    var comparisonInt = valueDate.compareTo(compareToDate);//remove line

    if (param.when == "after" && ((compareToDate.compareTo(valueDate)) < 0)) {
        fieldComparison = false;
        message = "Start date before End date";
    } else if (param.when == "before" && ((compareToDate.compareTo(valueDate)) < 0)) {
        fieldComparison = false;
        message = "End date before Start date";
    }
}

if (value.match(/^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d\d$/) && fieldComparison) {
    return true;
} else {
    return feedBackOverride(param);
}
```

}, messageFunction);

Now the logic is not complete, but I've gotten stuck as the when I choose a date from the datepicker it validates against the old value not the newly chosen value.

datepicker code is:

```
    $(".datepicker1").datepicker({
        minDate:0,
        dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
        yearRange : '-0:+10'
    });
```

Any ideas ofhow to force validation to wait until the field has actually completed?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a hidden field which validates this rule for you.

```
hiddenDate: {
            required: function() 
             {
                var MESSAGE = 'VALUES NOT ENTERED';

                //if Start Date and End Date is filled then do date comparison
                //otherwise return false since the fields are not filled.

                if($('#start_DATE').val() && $('#end_DATE').val() )
                {
                  /* Verify start and end dates are correctly formatted */

                  if(isStartDateValid && isEndDateValid)
                  {
                    var selectedStart =  $('#start_DATE').val();
                    var selectedEnd   =  $('#end_DATE').val();

                    if(selectedStart > selectedEnd)
                       MESSAGE = "Start date greater than end date" 
                    else
                       MESSAGE = "Start date smaller than end date" 

                   }

                }

              return MESSAGE ;
             }
            }
```

I have added the messages, which will be `true/false` values.

Comment: nice idea, i was thinking about using the datepicker select: method but that fits nicely into the rest of the validation logic. thanks Nupur